# BIRT with current database connecton

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, birt

I am using BIRT reporting (Scripting data source) in my Spring MVC web application.There are different databases for different group of users in my web application.When a particular user logged in, the database connection changes dynamically.
The problem is when the database get changes, BIRT report should get updated with current database,but it's not updating.
Please suggest way, how do I change BIRT database connection with current database connection dynamically using BIRT script.

Answer (score 0):

In my Maximo BIRT reports, the datasource is stored in a external source, outside of the report design file.

```
<data-sources>
        <script-data-source name="maximoDataSource" id="64" extends="MaximoSystemLibrary.maximoDataSource"/>
</data-sources>
```

I think the best solution is to change the contents of that source to the new database when the user logs in. That way your database changing logic remains in one place.

If there is only a limited number of databases, you could hardcode all the datasources and have a script in the report set somekind of global variable with the correct datasource name.
Each dataset starts with selecting the datasource:

```
maximoDataSet = MXReportDataSetProvider.create(this.getDataSource().getName(), this.getName());
maximoDataSet.open();
```

You could replace the this.getDataSource().getName() with the new global variable that points towards correct datasource.

Comment: I am using Scripting data source and when the user logs in then only database gets change but report database not updating and still connecting with the first database .